# .htaccess rewrite product URL to root category

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Having problems writing a rewrite rule, my regex skills are a bit lacking so I'm reading tutorials and working off examples... but can't seem to get it...

```
# from /boys/footwear/socks/surfs_up_kids_three-pack_socks/product.aspx?productid=4407&deptid=365
# to  /boys/footwear.html

RewriteRule ^.*boys/footwear/socks/([^/]+)/product\.aspx([^/]+)$ /boys/footwear.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

The idea is to match any products that have boys/footwear/socks and product.aspx assigned to it in the URL. Though I also want to be able to tweak it depending on the scenario... as it may not always be product.aspx

What am I doing wrong 1st off... cause thats the annoying part. I've followed dozens of tutorial and examples with no luck... and I know its the smallest thing...

Thanks for everyones input!

UPDATE

This is suppose to work according to: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
(But it does not work on the website?)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)boys/footwear/socks/(.*)/product.aspx(.*)$ $1boys/footwear/socks.html [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know rewrite regex usage, but since nobody answered yet, thought I might steer you in the right direction.

```
 # from /boys/footwear/socks/surfs_up_kids_three-pack_socks/product.aspx?productid=4407&deptid=365
 # to  /boys/footwear.html

 RewriteRule ^boys/footwear/socks/([^/]+)/product.aspx([^/]+)$
```

Just need to escape the dot between product and aspx.
Add capture groups as necessary to make up the replacement.

```
 ^.*/boys/footwear/socks/[^/]+/product\.aspx[^/]+$
```

Comment: You were right about the dot/period, it did need to be escaped. I didn't copy my latest version cause I was experimenting so took my last good reference copy. Thanks for certainly pointing it out.

I tried it with your version, and escaped my version. Neither worked. UPDATED the question with the updated rewrite that I have...

Comment: I would check the options, preliminary Rewrite parameters, and usage.